# Pandas pivot_table : a very surprising result with aggfunc len(x.unique()) and margins=True

Tags: python, pandas, unique, pivot-table

I am using pandas pivot_table with aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()) with margins=True. But I get a very surprising results : the column 'All' do not display to the sum of the rows values ! The results in column 'All' is systematically less than the sum.

[image]

How that is possible ?

Comment: I think it is bug

Comment: Output is same as `aggfunc=len`

Answer (score 2):

After spending several hours checking all the data and using the Excel pivot table function to understand what was happening here, I found the following (and very surprising) explanation:
margins=True does NOT calculate the sum of rows, but re-executes the aggfunc = lambda x: len (x.unique ()) command by applying it to all columns (ignoring the pivot_table 'columns' parameter). This explains why the sum displayed is always less than the true sum !!!
It is therefore necessary to be very careful using margin=true with aggfunc = lambda x: len (x.unique ()). Results may be unpredictable ...